# Use kernel programming function in C++ program

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, kernel

I am a newbie in this area & am writing a C++/assembly code to benchmark (measure execution time) of a section of a code in clock cycles. I need to disable pre-emption and hard interrupts through my code. I know that linux kernel development permits use of **preempt_disable()**; &raw_local_irq_save(flags) functions to do the same.

My question is that I am not writing a kernel module, but a normal C/C++ program in user space. Can I use these system calls through my C++ code (i.e. from user space/ no kernel module?) Which header files should i include. if yes. Can someone please give me reading references or examples?

Thanks!!

Comment: Doubt it.  You can try giving your process real-time scheduler priority.  If you really need this, make your code a module or device driver.  You can make it so reading your device returns the execution time of your test.  In practice running the test 10 times and comparing the results should give you a good answer.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I shall read up on these aspects

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this from userland application, especially disabling hardware interrupts, which provides the basis for many fundamental kernel functions like timekeeping.

What you can do instead is use [`sched_setscheduler(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) to set, say, `SCHED_FIFO` real-time priority, that is ask the kernel not to preempt your app until it voluntarily releases the CPU (usually a system call). Be careful though - you can easily lockup your system that way.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that is impossible. The kernel will not let you block interrupts.

But assigning yourself a very high prio is usally good enough.  Plus, make sure the benchmarked code runs long enough, e.g. by running it 10000 times in a loop.  That way, some interrupts don't matter in the overall cycle counting.  In my experience a code run time of 1 second is good enough (provided your system is not under heave stress) for home-brewn benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks cxxl! I shall try this solution & compare the results

Comment: Please consider upvoting if the answer was useful to you. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32242/202706

Comment: Sorry for that. I stuck to the advise on meta-SO: "I would suggest you maybe comment on a question by the OP, and make the OP aware that up-voting an answer is encouraged."

Comment: You may also find (on x86 at least) you get good enough accounting for time using the "perf" tools.